# Azure 2.6 SDK - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets not found on TFS Online

Tags: azure, tfs

According to https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-build-controller-vs
and
https://twitter.com/tfsbuck/status/595263582327025665

the tfs online build services should be updated. I just upgraded projects to 2.6 and checked them in to get the following:

```
The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.6\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found.
```

Have something changed with 2.6 or is it because my build service not yet has been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSO Host Build Controller has now been updated with Azure SDK 2.6.

You can see all the [supported software here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-build-controller-vs).